# Unable to set GPIO.HIGH. GPIO.LOW

Tags: rpi.gpio, relay

I am trying to control a relay with Pi3B.

Whenever I run `GPIO.setup(port, GPIO.OUT)` my relay starts working,

then any other command I try, eg. `GPIO.output(port, GPIO.HIGH)` or `GPIO.output(port, GPIO.LOW)` doesn't change the relay

Agian When I switch the `GPIO.setup(port, IN)` or `GPIO.cleanup()` my relay turns off. So only way I can control that relay is changing the IN/OUT mode of that port. What is missing here?

Here is my connection.

Relay `VCC` - Pi Board Pin 02

Relay `GND` - Pi Board Pin 06

Relay `IN`  - Pi Board pin 08

Relay is 220v- 5v one channel relay

Comment: Is your pin numbering correct? http://wiringpi.com/pins/

Comment: Try driving something simple (like a LED light) to factor the relay out of the problem.

Comment: Your relay module is not suitable for Pi control.  Buy a relay module which specifies it can be controlled by a 3.3V GPIO.